# What is the best way to search/find a point in a vector of points?

Tags: c++, opencv

I tried to sort the points based on their x coordinates and do a binary search on the vector but I cannot find the points that I know they exist.

Thanks for your help.

```
struct PointSort {
    bool operator() (cv::Point pt1, cv::Point pt2) { return (pt1.x < pt2.x);}
} mySort;

.
.
.
std::sort (temp.begin(), temp.end(), mySort);
if (std::binary_search(temp.begin(), temp.end(), somePoint, mySort)){
    doSomething();
}
```

Comment: Show what you tried. Have you looked at [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find)?

Comment: so you have 2d or 3d points and you want to search to see if a specific point is in the vector? or the closest one to your point or something similar ?

Comment: yes, I tried find as well. but apparently it can't compare points! I will add what I did.

Comment: @Raxvan I have 2D points. and I want to find specific points among them.

Comment: If your points have floating point components, it is difficult to find that exact point you look for, due to floating point inaccuracies

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So something like:

```
struct point { int x, y; };
std::vector<point> pts { {1,2}, {4,5} };
auto comp_x=[](const point& p1, const point& p2) {
    return p1.x < p2.x;
};
std::sort(begin(pts), end(pts), comp_x);
//using binary search
auto it=std::lower_bound(begin(pts), end(pts), some_point, comp_x);
//it now points to the point
```

The lower bound function uses a binary search to find the first element (`upper_bound` finds the last) and gives you an iterator to that element.

If you don't need it to be sorted, I would just use `std::find`.

```
auto it=std::find_if(begin(pts), end(pts), [&](const point& p) {
        return p.x==some_point.x;
    }
);
```

Comment: Talk about abusing `auto`, just to obfuscate.

Comment: @JamesKanze how on earth is that an abuse of auto? What would you do `std::vector<point>::const_iterator` that doesn't improve readability at all, it just INCREASES the dependency on container type. Why should I type out the name twice when the compiler knows what I am talking about?

Comment: Also please see: http://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/

Comment: "when the compiler knows what I am talking about": I was more worried about the person who has to read the code.  But my comment wasn't aimed so much at the iterator, but the `auto` for the lambda.  (And I'm afraid that Herb comes up with about as many anti-patterns as good ideas.  He's exceptionally good at explaining things, but software engineering isn't really his strong point.)

Comment: @JamesKanze WTF how else would you do the lambda, write it out completely at each callsite? Pay the overhead penalty of `std::function` with more typing, no thanks. I really really don't think `auto` in these cases can be considered an anti patterns. The following would be `auto i=3;` and `auto s=std::string{};` but for lambda and iterators I have to strongly disagree, especially when their scope is so localised. "but software engineering isn't really his strong point", right, whatever.

Comment: On the other hand, your *first* lambda doesn't need to capture ;)

Comment: @leemes I wish I could have you looking over my code as I write it, I'd never have to do the compiler-fix-compiler loop. :)

Comment: Well, the additional capture doesn't hurt the compiler, it's simply nicer to avoid it if unnecessary. For quickly writing code for SO, I recommend http://ideone.com or similar sites.

Comment: yeah I know, but I meant in general (I am a big fan of pair programming).

Comment: @111111 Ah okay, that's a big compliment, thanks ;) In the past I used to think "ah I don't know if this compiles, simply try and see", but now I think it's better to learn to review the own code before compiling and trying to detect possible mistakes right away. This has a big advantage: There are some mistakes the compiler simply can't detect and if you're used to type code lazily you can get in trouble easily. I mean, everyone makes mistakes, but if you get more pedantic with yourself *while typing* you're safer.

Comment: Why do you want a lambda?  Either the operation is very specific to this particular call (not the case here), and you use a lambda, or it is more general, and you define a functional object outside of the function (since it's going to be used by more than one function).  (But we're probably not that far apart; _if_ there is a case where you might want to use a lambda more than once in the same function, `auto` is probably the preferred solution there as well, since you can't really spell out the type; I just can't think of such a case.  So I probably overreacted.  My apologies.)

Comment: @JamesKanze no because sometimes the functor is local to the function using it, or local to a sequence of calls not just one.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to find a `Point` that matches the one you are supplying:

```
std::vector<Point> points;
// points is filled somewhere
Point p { 1, 2 };
std::vector<Point>::iterator it = std::find(points.begin(), points.end(), p);
```

If you wanted to customize the comparison, you can use `std::find_if`:

```
Point pt { 1, 2 };
std::vector<Point>::iterator it = std::find_if(points.begin(), points.end(), [&](const Point& p)
{
    return pt.x == p.x;
});
```

And for God's sake, ignore the "AAA" nonsense ...

Side note:  your vector does not need to be sorted to use `std::find` (though it will speed it up if it is).  And if you can use the C++11 standard, you do not need to create a functor:

```
std::sort(temp.begin(), temp.end(), [](const Point& p1, const Point& p2)
{
    return p1.x < p2.x;
});
```

Additionally, if the elements of your `Point` class are floating point numbers, you will not want to use straight equality for comparisons.  Instead, pick some small number as your lowest acceptable precision (*epsilon*), and compare the difference between 2 values to it:

```
float x = SOME_VALUE;
float y = SOME_OTHER_VALUE;
float EPSILON = 0.000000001;
bool are_equal = std::abs(x - y) < EPSILON;
```

Comment: No you should not ignore the AAA "nonsense"... Especially for these iterators, `auto` is perfect.

Comment: @Zac yeah, because you code (second listing) is SO much more readable?  (Rhetorical), and I suppose you are much better authority on the matter than Sutter.

Comment: @leemes Replacing `std::vector<Point>::iterator it = ...` with `auto it = ...` is a great way to receive a smackdown in a code review.  There are typically 2 reasons I see for doing such:  1) shorter typing, and 2) it allows you to change the container without having to update the type definition.  In 1), that is just laziness and as such is irrelevant.  In 2), if you are changing the container type, there are likely a lot of other concerns you'll have to take care of as well, so updating your iterator declarations is the least of your worries.

Comment: @111111 Yes, it is.  It is structured like a loop, which makes it very easy to read and debug - and conveys the actual behavior to someone else reading my code.  Declaring an `auto` pointer-to-a-function that is only used once is pointless.  And while I agree with Herb on a lot of things, AAA is not one of them.

Comment: In many places not using auto or not using a typedef for the iterator would get you scolded in a code review.  Your way isn't the only way.

Comment: @ZacHowland read my code, it's not used once, it's used twice, once in `sort` and again in `lower_bound`. Of course if I used it once I'd of just used it as a param no on is suggesting otherwise.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I've never been anywhere where not using `auto` (or the C# equivalent `var`) would get you scolded.  Typically, I would recommend a typedef, but it is a bit overkill to answer a question on SO.  And I never said my way is the only way ... I simply said that the AAA philosophy is flawed (and there are many senior software engineers who agree with me on that).

Comment: @111111 And if you notice, none of my lamdbas are used more than once.

Comment: I thought you were using it for my code in reference to the lambda, and in your own in reference to the iterators. In your code listing, I think the use of `auto` over `std::vector<Point>::iterator` would be a tangible improvement.

Comment: @111111 I disagree.  As I stated before, the reasons for doing so typically boil down to laziness or a flawed assertion that you can quickly change to a different container type without having to update any other elements of your code.  Scott Meyers has an item (I can't really the number of the top of my head) dealing with a different issue that has the same logic behind it and he shoots it down quickly - if you change your container, there are a lot of other things you'll have to look at.  If you have `typedef std::vector<int> IntVector;`, then declaring `IntVector::iterator = ...` (cont).

Comment: Is descriptive and not cumbersome.  If you were to change to `typedef std::list<int> IntVector`, it is still valid, and still descriptive.  Using `auto it = ...` is not cumbersome, but also not descriptive.  As a side note:  if you switched from `std::vector` to `std::list`, you would no longer be able to use `std::sort` ... which means you would be forced to update your code anyway.  The point being, when you write code, you should do so to make it clear to the next person reading it (which is where the AAA philosophy falls flat).

Comment: The more code, the more risks of getting it wrong. The more `auto`, the less code, the less risk. This applies *most* of the time (there are exceptions) and the main argument of "AAA". Especially for reviews, the valuable time of the reviewers should not be wasted in checking if this is really the correct iterator to be used (e.g. const or not?) or if an explicit type makes optimizations like lazy evaluation in the case of template expression libraries like "Eigen" impossible. These are only some examples where `auto` is *awesome*. Your arguments only show that you're not yet used to using it.

Comment: Only in the very loosest sense of the word does `auto it = ...` mean more code than `vector<type>::iterator it = ...`.  In fact, it is far more likely that attempting to not think about the type you are dealing with in a strongly-typed language will lead to errors.  You write code not just to be clear to the compiler, but also to the next developer that has to read and maintain your code.  Making it as explicit as possible makes his (or her) job *much* easier and will keep your picture from being placed over the team dart-board.  `auto` has its place, but "AAA" is a massive abuse of it.